# problema con el codigo del servicio para ionic

Tags: ionic, typescript, angular4

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

let apiUrl = "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/";

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

 

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }
 
  postData(credentials, type) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       let headers = new Headers();

       return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify({credentials}),{ headers: headers })
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

{ headers: headers} <- ese pedazo de linea me tira error.

Comment: ¿Qué error se muestra?

Comment: { headers: headers} <- esta linea me tira error, y aun con el cambio me sigue mostrando error en esa parte.

Comment: ¿Podrías copiar la totalidad del error?

Comment: return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify({credentials}),{ headers: headers })

Comment: En esa linea me tira error, ahora tengo un cambio y aun asi me da error.

Comment: Repito, ¿Podrías copiar la totalidad del error?, No la linea donde da el error, el stacktrace, te tiene que salir en la consola del browser .

Comment: Eso es el error en consola.
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/Signup", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse",

Comment: posiblemente sea porque el objeto headers, va vacio

Comment: Si el error es en tiempo de ejecución y es "status 404" eso sólo significa que la URL es incorrecta

Comment: Hola, no estaría mal que echaras un vistazo al [tour] y [ask] y que para luego [edit] tu pregunta. Deberías cambiar el pantallazo por código y mostrar toda la traza del error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es necesario ajustar el código así:

> - Cambiar `Headers` por `HttpHeaders`
> - Quitar `rxjs/add/operator/map`
> - Agregar tipado
> - Implementar *HttpHeaders*
> - Quitar el encabezado `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ya que no es un encabezado del cliente, si no del servidor
> - Quitar el `.json()` del *response* ya que la respuesta ya es un JSON
> - Para acceder a la propiedad `apiUrl` desde un método es necesario el uso del `this` para que pueda acceder, `this.apiUrl`

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {
  private apiUrl: string = "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/";

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  public postData(credentials, type): Promise<any> {
    let httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer TOKEN`
      })
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), httpOptions).subscribe(
        res => {
          resolve(res);
        },
        err => {
          reject(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
}
```

[Revisar la documentación oficial de HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta forma, definiendo `Headers` y asignándole el `content-type`, ya que le envías un Json y no debería ir vació el `Header` tampoco.

**Código:**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';



@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {
  private apiUrl = "http://localhost/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/";
  private headers = new Headers();

  constructor(public http: HttpClient,
  ) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }

  postData(credentials, type): Promise<any> {

    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials),options)
        .subscribe(res => {
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });

  }

}
```

Comment: Me  marco rojo  en dos partes,
 let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); y
return this.http.post(apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), options)

Comment: Un error en el apuro, ahí lo acomode al parecer. Pero podrías escribir el tipo de error, es mas fácil ayudarte así.

Comment: Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", error: error },

Comment: la variable options me marca en rojo, por que no creo que la ruta este mala.

Comment: Baja `apiUrl =` dentro de la Class, no me había percatado de eso.

Comment: this.http.post(this.apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), options) 
la variable options me marca en rojo y en consola me tira un error totalmente distinto .

Comment: Copiame el error, si es distinto.

Comment: error: error {target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false}
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map }
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse() }

Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en http://localhost/htdocs/PHP-Slim-Restful/api/Signup. (Razón: Cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no presente)

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` Ese es el problema, prueba con el cambio que realice. Y dime si cambia.

Comment: por consola aun me da el error de ' Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
PD : si tienes alguna guia o algo para como hacer un login conectado a la bdd con ionic 3 me serviria.

Comment: Typescript Error
Argument of type 'RequestOptions' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht.' Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]:string | string[]; }'.Type 'Headers' is not assignable to type '{ [header: string]: string | string[]; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'Headers'.
 
ESE es un el error que aparece cuando hago ionic serve

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/estoyseguro/src/providers/auth-service/auth-service.ts
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{this.http.post(this.apiUrl + type, JSON.stringify(credentials), options)
.subscribe(res =>{

Comment: `import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';  `
`private headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  });` El error que dice ahi es por el tipo de `headers` al parecer, cámbialo por este.